# Show $a+b\leq\frac{8}{27}$

Tags: polynomials, roots

We have a polynomial $f(x)=x^3-x^2+ax+b$ with $a,b$ real numbers. If $x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}$ are the roots of $f$ and are positive real numbers show that $a+b\leq\frac{8}{27}$.
I showed using Viete formulas and identities that $a+b\leq\frac{1}{3}$. But I dont know where the $8$ should come from.

Comment: Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Follow these guidelines to get help in this forum. It's particularly important that you share your own work and thoughts on the problem to show that you have made a serious effort by yourself before asking for help, and you're not just trying to get others to solve it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AM-GM!

$2=(1-x_1)+(1-x_2)+(1-x_3) \ge 3 \times (f(1))^\frac13$